# is there a way to use cilium to rate limit tls connection establishment?

Tags: performance, kubernetes, ssl, networking

I want to do something like

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -m state --state NEW -p tcp -m limit --limit 12/minute --dport 12871 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -m state --state NEW -p tcp --dport 12871 -j DROP
```

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1095491/how-to-limit-connections-to-1-connect-on-5-seconds-iptables
but via cilium/natively on kubernetes
to protect my ingresses from falling over if many clients reconnect at the same time

Answer (score -2):

I suppose you can, yes. This is done via the `api-rate-limit` configuration option that you will have to configure for your `cilium-agent` running on the node.

Your limit above will translate to:

```
--api-rate-limit endpoint-create=rate-limit:12/m
```

You can read more about this option [here](https://docs.cilium.io/en/v1.9/configuration/api-rate-limiting/#valid-duration-values).

Comment: This is not what the api-rate-limit does. The api-rate-limit is a limit for API calls to the cilium agent, limiting the rate at which cilium will create endpoints, not limiting the throughput of the endpoints.